# How do I accept all Networks with the same ssid with wicd?

Tags: networking, wifi

We have a Mesh network here in my town, where every node creates the same client wlan with the SSID "kiel.freifunk.net".

In `wicd` I can connect to those networks, but I have to choose which of them.

In network-manager it was more handy: there was shown only one network with that SSID and if I moved through the room with my laptop, it automatically connects to the nearest network with that SSID name (I think that's called "roaming")

Is it possible to achieve this with `wicd` also?

Comment: Have you tried the first comment suggestion here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/wicd/+bug/661373 ?

Comment: I will try, but how can I test it? I have accepted all Networks im My house already... maybe tomotrrow, when I am in another part of the town. I will see if it connects automatically there now that I checked "Share these values for all the networks sharing this ESSID" on all those Networks

Comment: Remove all the accepted networks at home with the same SSID, except one, make sure the "Share these values..." is checked, then cover the AP with a chernobyl-style cement cask and see what happens ;-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: can you post that as answer? I will mark is as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all the accepted networks at home with the same SSID, except one (let's call this the "template"), and then make sure the "Share these values..." option is checked.

Now, the next time the "template" network can no longer sustain the connection, `Wicd` should recognize one of the other available networks as the same and try to roam to the next available AP

Comment: I can't find this in `wicd-gtk`; do I need to use a different client?

Comment: How do I "Remove all the accepted networks at home with the same SSID"?